# How can I pass the contents of a file for use as a paramter?

Tags: shell-script

I have a file `1.txt` with 10 rows.
I want to pass each row sequentially to `sed` and save the output in a log.

```
job=`tail -1 1.txt`
getdd=`grep $job "mainlog.log"| sed -n '1p' $i > /tmp/result.log
```

Comment: You are missing one ` in the end of second command I guess.

Comment: You're really creating a new user to ask another question on the same issue ?! But it's getting slowly better. Please add the content of 1.txt, mainlog.log and what the expected result should look like ...

Comment: What are you expecting to land in the variable `getdd` since your `sed` gets written to `/tmp/result.log` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unclear from your question `getdd` seems to be useless, because it will not get any value.

You can use `while` loop:

```
while read -r job;
do
 grep "$job" "mainlog.log"| sed -n '1p' "$i" >> /tmp/result.log
done < 1.txt
```

Comment: `$i` is just a leftover from an earlier stage of that script where op tried to use something like `for i in $(cat file)`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495260/storing-result-in-variable-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

I would use xargs

```
xargs -a 1.txt -I{} sh -c 'grep "$1" mainlog.log | head -n 1' _ {} > /tmp/result.log
```

or same as while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r job; do
    grep "$job" mainlog.log | head -n 1
done < 1.txt > /tmp/result.log
```

Comment: i m stil getting /tmp/result.log as 0 byte only even after using  below code                               while IFS= read -r job; do
    grep "$job" mainlog.log | head -n 1
done < 1.txt > /tmp/result.log

Comment: please follow my advice from comment above. Please add the content of 1.txt, mainlog.log and what the expected result should look like ...

Comment: Actually data is huge ,really difficult to add here and i my requirement ,is just  from 1.txt ($job varible) i need to pass it to main .log and perform sed and grep operation which i have mentioned.